# symfony doctrine data-dump and reload wont't work

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, console, doctrine

I have a database built by Doctrine from schema.yml which I want to modify. Thus, first I saved the data using *doctrine:data-dump* command. Afterwards I wanted to check if it really can reload data, so I called the *doctrine:build --all --and-load* command.

It successfully rebuilt the database, however when loading data from data1.yml file(where I saved beforehand) it gives me the following error:

> Couldn't call Doctrine_Core::set(),
>   second argument should be an instance
>   of Doctrine_Collection when setting
>   one-to-many references.

I would really appreciate if you guys could help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's not really possible to dump the database with data-dump and load it later with data-load without any additional steps (talking about more complicated schemas). You need to manually modify your fixtures a bit.

The reason is those tools were not made with such scenario in mind.

The right approach with changing schema is to use doctrine migrations.